# sigset_t with 64bit target using microsoft cl.exe from visual studio 2019

Tags: c, windows, signals, cl

I'm trying to compile some old C code from a decade ago and am getting errors for the `sigset_t` type. I've researched the issue on the net and here on SO without success. I also tried adding `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE` too, but all without success. Maybe something has been deprecated since the code was working and has a new replacement now.

I'm wondering if someone can tell me what to do to fix the issue? Thank you

Here's is what it looks like on my end:

```
I set my command line environment for compiling 64bit by running the usual batch file (vcvars64.bat)
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

I am using this cl.exe compiler:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe


C:\ufo-dev\code>make all
cl   /c /Od /nologo /MT /I. "-I..\s" "-Ic:\ufo-dev\include"   ..\s\spool.c
spool.c
..\s\spool.c(85): error C2065: 'sigset_t': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(85): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'set'
..\s\spool.c(85): error C2065: 'set': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(86): error C2065: 'sigset_t': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(86): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'old'
..\s\spool.c(86): error C2065: 'old': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(298): error C2065: 'set': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(299): error C2065: 'set': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(300): error C2065: 'set': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(300): error C2065: 'SIGHUP': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(301): error C2065: 'set': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(301): error C2065: 'SIGQUIT': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(302): error C2065: 'set': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(303): error C2065: 'SIG_BLOCK': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(303): error C2065: 'set': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(303): error C2065: 'old': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(338): error C2065: 'SIG_UNBLOCK': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(338): error C2065: 'set': undeclared identifier
..\s\spool.c(338): error C2065: 'old': undeclared identifier
make: *** [spool.obj] Error 2

/* typedefs in an include file that is included */
mytypedefs.h:
#define dcl_sigsett(x)          sigset_t x

spool.c:
#define _POSIX_SOURCE                   /* enables POSIX compiler options */
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE                 /* enables POSIX compiler options */
#include<mytypedefs.h>
#include <signal.h>                     /* signals */

spool.c(85):
    dcl_sigsett (set);          /* set of signals to block */
    dcl_sigsett (old);          /* set of signals to block */

spool.c(298):
/* : - block signals while rewriting the mailbox! */
        sigemptyset (&set);
        sigaddset (&set, SIGINT);
        sigaddset (&set, SIGHUP);
        sigaddset (&set, SIGQUIT);
        sigaddset (&set, SIGTERM);
        sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &set, &old);
```

Comment: Windows doesn't support posix signals. Try on a different OS, or maybe in a WSL2 session.

Comment: Well, that explains why it doesn't work! Thank you for your answer!